# Give developer access to dev site only

Tags: centos, file-permissions, webserver

Okay, so I've got our web user for the live site, also the cpanel user, and a new user develop. Our site path goes:

```
/home/user/public_html/dev
```

I need to give user develop permissions to write ONLY to the dev folder without changing owners or group permissions (I tried, it tossed me a 500 error). Is it even possible?

I've tried changing the dev folder ownership recursively to make the developer the owner, the only issue is that because the developer isn't the cpanel user, it threw the 500 error. I even tried to

> usermod -a -G cpaneluser develop

to add the developer to the main cpanel user group (didn't know if its possible), and still no avail.

I know I can chroot him to the dev directory, but getting him to be able to edit everything in the dev directory without changing ownership of any files in it is the hard part.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what your situation is? What did you do to create the user, what did you do to change the ownership? What are the permissions of said folder? A 500 error means an error you get this in a browser when you try to access… what, exactly? Is the dev user connecting via SSH, even?

Comment: I was actually looking into chroot when I posted this, though the issue is that even if I chroot him to /home/user/public_html/dev, he's still unable to edit anything in that folder since I can't change owners. The owner is xxx, and I've even added the dev to the xxx group to try as a workaround, no avail.

Comment: Please include the permissions of the relevant directories, at least of `~/public_html/dev` and `~/public_html/`. Also, include what you actually _did_. What did you try and get a 500 error? In any case, that error is a browser code, I assume you have root access to the server and are using command-line commands right? For the question to be reopened, you need to add the new information to the question itself.

Comment: Just added more info.

Comment: Also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

As I noticed you mentioned about cpaneluser, why not just create another FTP account under that cPanel account, and assign it to the /dev directory ?

Comment: I was trying to find a way that he could have access to the commands he needs, yet not full server access.